# What should I do when there is no ID, name, etc. and driver.find_elements_by_xpath won't work?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am trying to pull the "next moonrise" time of 12:05 am (towards the top of [this](https://www.timeanddate.com/moon/usa/tallahassee) page).  It has no name, ID, and when I run the following xpath it doesn't work:

```
nextMoonRise = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[6]/main/article/section[1]/div/div[3]/p[7]/text()')
```

The error I am receiving is:

```
 "selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "/html/body/div[1]/div[6]/main/article/section[1]/div/div[3]/p[7]/text()" is: [object Text]. It should be an element."
```

Note: Xpath is working fine, I have used it other times. It is this specific piece of data that is giving me issues.

Comment: can you mark your element in page and update with screenshot i could not find moonrise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/text()` is not valid `.text` is attribute to get the text from an element

```py
nextMoonRise = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[6]/main/article/section[1]/div/div[3]/p[7]')
print(nextMoonRise.text)
>>> Next Moonrise: Tomorrow00:05
```

Comment: This did in fact work.  The solution was to use the xpath attached to the entire <p> rather than the specific data I was looking for.  Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

We can access web-element those don't have attributes like name,ID,Class...

Currently you are using absolute xpath, following Xpath will help to get only the time of the next moon rise. Below is the relative path. try to use following kind of xpath express. it will have lot of benefits.

```
.//p[contains(.,'Next Moonrise: ')]/text()
```

Please let me if you know more about it.